# Server think NSMutableURLRequest "POST" parameter is "GET"

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, http-headers, nsurlsession

I'm having an issue in an iOS app with NSMutableURLRequest. I set the header to "POST", and load the dictionary into the request, but I get an error page back in the response, and a check of the server log shows the message:

```
"org.springframework.web.HtpRequestMethodNotSupportedEception: Request method 'GET' not supported"
```

The server side code is set up correctly as it has been working for a long while without any changes. I'm changing the client side from a RestKit implementation to using native iOS apis such as NSURLSessionConfiguration, NSURLSession, NSURLSessionUploadTask and and NSMutableURLRequest.

Below is the code, where you can see I've set up the URL request with the "Post" Parameter. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
            //Set the url string to send post for products
            NSString* command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mobile/%@/addProductJson.do", [configuration serverUrl],[configuration authKey]];

            // Create the actual url
            NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:command];

            NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;


            // Create the request and set the header to post
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myUrl];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


            //Create dictionary for uploads
            NSMutableDictionary* upcDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


            for(NSManagedObject *matches in arrScans)
            {
                [arrUp addObject: [matches valueForKey:@"upc"]];
            };


            [upcDict setObject:arrUp forKey:@"upc"];
            [upcDict setObject:@"myMobileList" forKey:@"listName"];


            NSError* error = nil;

            // create the data to be sent
            NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:upcDict options:0 error:&error];

            if (!error)
            {
                NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask =
                    [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                            fromData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)
                {
}];
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"success");

                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"No");
                    }


                    [uploadTask resume];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"JSON error");
            }
            [upcDict release];
        }
```

One important addendum - printing the headers using this statement:

```
NSLog(@"all request fields: %@ ", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
```

shows an empty array.

Comment: You should set a type of content in the request header
E.g.

`[mutableRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`


See this lib:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the content type, but no love. I'm going to dump this and go with AFNetworking, I guess, but it's frustrating I can't get a simple http post to work.

Comment: @mozilla - your answer was correct, although when I tried it previously it didn't work - I had also added "   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];" I wonder if that messed it up? Anyway, if you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.